# Sum operation on Textbox

Tags: jquery

I have multiple textboxes (with class `txtsum`) which should allow only numbers. How can I calculate the sum of all these textboxes as the user types in the textbox

```
var $txtb = $(':input.txtsum');
$txtb.on('change',function(){
    tot = 0.0;
    $txtb.each(function() {
        tot += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Can you suggest me the right/better way to do it? Here's what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/DPe4W/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
tot += parseFloat($(this).text());
```

to

```
tot += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

You should use `.val` to get the value of any input elements like `input`, `select`.

Also I changed your code like below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DPe4W/7/

```
var $txtb = $(':input.txtsum');
$txtb.on('keyup', function() {
    var tot = 0.0;
    $txtb.each(function() {
        var val = parseFloat(this.value);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {   
           tot += val;
        }
    });

    $("p").html(tot);
});
```

Comment: @KayKay Change `MooTools` to `jQuery` in the top left

Comment: @KayKay Updated answer with a demo.

Comment: perfect..the total happens when I shift focus to the next textbox. Is there a way to calculate as I am typing?

Comment: @KayKay See updated answer and the DEMO. You just need to change `change` to `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` does not work with input types.. Use `.val()`  instead

Instead of

```
 $(this).text()
```

use

```
($(this).val() ; // To calculate the value
```

**FULL CODE**

```
    var $txtb = $(':input.txtsum');
$txtb.on('keyup', function() {
    tot = 0.0;
    $txtb.each(function() {
        var t = $(this).val() != '' ? $(this).val() : 0;
        tot += parseFloat(t);
    });
    $("p").html(tot);
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/DPe4W/6/)**

Comment: How do I display the total in para?

Comment: First change the framework to jQuery instead of MooTools...Need to move the block where youa re writing to the para to outside of the for loop.  Otherwise it overwrites the current value